# Using IterativeSplineParameterization with computeCartesianPath

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I've been trying to use the recently merged in IterativeSplineParameterization  (https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/441) trajectory processer without having to install moveit from source but I haven't been able to find a config file that allows me to do so. Has anyone used this algorithm without installing from source ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326511/using-iterativesplineparameterization-with-computecartesianpath/) by [mjs](https://answers.ros.org/users/43265/mjs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit:

Your comment completely changes your question (please include all relevant information in your first post in the future), so here is an answer to the new question.

> I’m specifically looking to use the iterative spline parametrization for Cartesian planning. Would updating this config file change the algorithm used by both freespace and cartesian plans ?

No, it doesn't, as the default implementation of `computeCartesianPath(..)` hard-codes the use of the `IterativeParabolicTimeParameterization` right now ([here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/b6de3e1d309df9f65d47b9ad0c2dc599a0f7b32c/moveit_ros/move_group/src/default_capabilities/cartesian_path_service_capability.cpp#L155-L158)).

> I would change the object instantiated here https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/ee02b0b0886c515b721298e7365660c1e7413279/moveit_ros/move_group/src/default_capabilities/cartesian_path_service_capability.cpp#L159

yes, you would have to do that.

You could potentially avoid building all of MoveIt from source by extracting the [move_group](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/tree/b6de3e1d309df9f65d47b9ad0c2dc599a0f7b32c/moveit_ros/move_group) package from the source tree, adapting the adapter and then building that.

Even better: create a copy of the adapter, place it in its own package and just build that.

Best: make this configurable (using a parameter), test it and submit a PR against `ros-planning/moveit` and get it merged.

---

There should be no need to build MoveIt from source (I'm also not entirely sure what you'd be changing specifically in that case).

The time parameterisation is done in a MoveIt *Planning Request Adapter*.

There are three of those, corresponding to the three algorithms currently available:

- `AddTimeParameterization` (which applies the Iterative Parabolic Time Parameterization)
- `AddIterativeSplineParameterization` (the spline based approach: Iterative Spline Parameterization)
- `AddTimeOptimalParameterization` (using the Time-optimal Trajectory Generation library by Tobias Kunz)

So changing the algorithm used is a matter of changing the configuration of the planning request adapters.

For MoveIt configurations generated by the MoveIt Setup Assistant, that can be done by editing the `ompl_planning_pipeline.launch.xml` file.

Specifically, change [this line](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/f842b1f852ad6ff1b8c8cf8772c327bff75f5c68/moveit_setup_assistant/templates/moveit_config_pkg_template/launch/ompl_planning_pipeline.launch.xml#L14) and replace `AddTimeParameterization` with `AddIterativeSplineParameterization`.

Refer to the [Time Parameterization](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/time_parameterization/time_parameterization_tutorial.html) page in the MoveIt documentation for some more info on this.

And refer to the [planning_request_adapters_plugin_description.xml](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/471ebbe7918786f8d6f6ba69cce1f0001ddb2a2c/moveit_ros/planning/planning_request_adapters_plugin_description.xml#L34-L48) file for a list of available time parameterisation planning request adapters.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjs](https://answers.ros.org/users/43265/mjs/) on 2019-06-21**:
Thank you! I’m specifically looking to use the iterative spline parametrization for Cartesian planning. Would updating this config file change the algorithm used by both freespace and cartesian plans ?

As for building from source, I would change the object instantiated here https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/ee02b0b0886c515b721298e7365660c1e7413279/moveit_ros/move_group/src/default_capabilities/cartesian_path_service_capability.cpp#L159

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-22**:\

> I’m specifically looking to use the iterative spline parametrization for Cartesian planning.

Your original question did not mention this. Could you please add these sort of details to your question in the future?

**Comment by [mjs](https://answers.ros.org/users/43265/mjs/) on 2019-06-22**:
Yes sorry about that, I will make sure to do so in the future

**Comment by [Xinjue](https://answers.ros.org/users/107780/xinjue/) on 2023-02-21**:
I think this answer should be included in the tutorial